# How to persist elements on shopping cart?

Tags: php, jquery

I need help to solve this problem.

I have an input that specifies the amount a user wants to order on a product. When the "Add to cart" button is pressed, the buyer basket must also display the quantity ordered for that product. So far, I have only been able to display the image, the product name and the price (they are saved in the database and I take over them), but I can not even display the quantity (not saved in the database) that they want command.

I'm storing products in my cart using user session.
Thanks!

This is my code.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="summary entry-summary">

       <h1 class="shorter"><strong><?php echo $item_rs['product_name']; ?></strong></h1>

       <p class="price">
       <span class="amount"><?php echo $item_rs['product_price'] . ' $'; ?></span>
    </p>

    <p class="taller"><?php echo $item_rs['product_description']; ?> </p>

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="cart">
        <div class="quantity">
            <input type="button" class="minus" value="-">
            <input type="text" class="input-text qty text" title="Qty" value="1" name="quantity" min="1" step="1">
            <input type="button" class="plus" value="+">
        </div>
        <button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary btn-icon add-cart" data-id="<?php echo $item_rs['id_prod']; ?>">Add to cart</button>
    </form>
</div> </div>
```

And this is the code from shipping cart:

```
<tbody>
<?php
if(isset($arrayIds)) {
    foreach($arrayIds as $value) {
        $cart_sql = 'SELECT * FROM produs WHERE id_prod=' . $value;
        if($cart_query = mysqli_query($dbconnect, $cart_sql)) {
            $cart_rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cart_query);
        }
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td class="product-thumbnail">
                <img width="80" height="80" alt=""
                     class="img-responsive"
                     src="img/products/<?php echo $cart_rs['img_name']; ?>">
            </td>
            <td class="product-name">
                <?php echo $cart_rs['product_description']; ?><span
                    class="amount"></span><br>
                <?php echo $cart_rs['product_price'].' $'; ?>
            </td>
            <td class="product-quantity">

            </td>
            <td class="product-actions">
                <a title="Delete product" data-id="<?php echo $cart_rs['id_prod']; ?>" class="remove" href="#">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
</tbody>
```

Seding the user session is made using jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click', '.add-cart',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var data_id = $(this).attr('data-id');

            $.post('set_storage.php', {id: data_id});
            location.reload();
        });
    });
</script>
```

And this is the file "set_storage.php" :

```
<?php
session_start();

$arrayIds = $_SESSION["id"];
if ($arrayIds) {
    $_SESSION["id"] = $arrayIds . ", " . $_POST['id'];
} else {
    $_SESSION["id"] = $_POST['id'];
}

?>
```

Comment: So, why don't you store the quantity in the user's session?

Comment: You can also store your cart in browser local storage.

Comment: why is this tagged with Javascript and jQuery? It appears to be a pure PHP problem. (And you say you are storing data in the session, but don't show any code which either reads from or writes to the session.)

Comment: same as @NicoHaase I'm a bit confuse

Comment: @NicoHaase can you guid me through that process?

Answer (score 0):

It could work if you store your IDs this way:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['productsInCart'])) {
  $_SESSION['productsInCart'] = array();
}

$productIdToAdd = $_POST['id'];

if(isset($_SESSION['productsInCart'][$productIdToAdd]) === false) {
  $_SESSION['productsInCart'][$productIdToAdd] = 0;
}

$_SESSION['productsInCart'][$productIdToAdd]++;
?>
```

Now, the array `$_SESSION['productsInCart']` holds the ID of each product in the cart as the key and the number of items per product as the value